# Duvida com PHP file_get_contents

Tags: php

o meu codigo rodando no pc funciona 100% mas quando jogo no servidor ele nao captura as informações. segue codigo para que voces me ajudem

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://jsuol.com.br/c/_template/v1/_geral/css/styles.css?&file=geral&type=parse&versao=v1&plataforma=web&portal=uol&media=webpage&cache=19t3e89gn" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://jsuol.com.br/c/_template/v1/_geral/css/styles.css?&file=especifico&type=parse&versao=v1&plataforma=web&portal=uol&estacao=economia&estacao-id=economia&cache=19t3e89gn" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://jsuol.com.br/c/_template/v1/web/uol/css/internas/economia/cotacoes/styles-cotacoes.css?&cache=19t3e89gn" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://jsuol.com.br/c/economia/cotacoes/cotacoes.css?v13&&cache=19t3e89gn" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://jsuol.com.br/c/_template/v1/web/uol/css/estrutura/conteudo-auxiliar.css?&cache=19t3e89gn" />
<?php

$url = file_get_contents('http://economia.uol.com.br/cotacoes/');
preg_match_all('/<section class="barra-ticker pg-bgcolor3">(.+)<\/p> <\/li> <\/ul> <\/div> <\/section>/s', $url, $conteudo);
$exibir = $conteudo[0][0];
$retirar = array('');
$exibir = str_replace($retirar, '', $exibir);
echo $exibir;
                ?>
```

Comment: Você já deu CHMD 777 na pasta do arquivo?

Comment: pode ser chmod 775.

Comment: Talvez você precise habilitar: `ini_get('allow_url_open')` ou ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 1)` não precisa ir até o `php.ini` se não tiver acesso.

Comment: Se quiser pode fazer pelo arquivo .htaccess, basta colocar essa regra nele: php_value allow_url_fopen On

Comment: ao dar CHMD 775 na pasta gera um erro na pagina 

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@ruralrio.com.br to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.4.12 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 Server at ruralrio.com.br Port 80

Comment: http://ruralrio.com.br/bolsa/bolsauol.php

Comment: O error_reporting está ativado?

Comment: esta,
e o mais engraçado e que tem outra pagina que mostra certinho que a parte de cotações ruralrio.com.br/milho.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vá ate o arquivo `php.ini` e mude as seguintes linhas;

De:
`allow_url_fopen = Off`

Para:
`allow_url_fopen = On`

Caso não tenha acesso ao `php.ini` você também pode utilizar;

`ini_get('allow_url_open')` ou `ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 1)`

caso não funcione...

Você também pode usar `CURL` para fazer isso, logo apos a abertura da tag de PHP na sua pagina em questão coloque o código abaixo:

```
function my_file_get_contents( $site_url ){
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5; // set to zero for no timeout
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site_url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
ob_start();
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$file_contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return $file_contents;
}
```

Agora ao invés de usar `file_get_contents('http://.....')` voce pode usar `my_file_get_contents('http://.....')`

Encontrei em alguns foruns a seguinte frase:

> O problema será solucionado, o uso da função file_get_contentes é uma falha grave de segurança, sendo recomendado criar a função cURL acima.

Comment: pelo meu phpinfo essas funções estao ativas (http://ruralrio.com.br/phpinfo.php)

Comment: não mostra nenhum erro @CristianoCardosoSilva ?

Comment: Nao aparece nem um erro

Comment: e o mais engraçado e que tem outra pagina que mostra certinho que a parte de cotações http://ruralrio.com.br/milho.php